# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidJdkImage'

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle, frontend, computer-science

I encountered similar problem multiple times a row. I tried to uninstall everything and try from the start but it still failed in installing the application. Also there is no module found upon running the app using npm start and npm run android. I followed some ways to solve in the internet but it is till not working.
[Windows error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFksA.png)

Here is my build.gradle

[Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFTCl.png)